# Are the movie events taking place in the UK?

Tags: the-best-offer

I know that *The Best Offer* has been [shot in Italy and Central Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Best_Offer#Production), but the events shown in the movie seem to be taking place in an English-speaking country.
I'm wondering if this was supposed to be United Kingdom.
Is there anything in the movie or external sources that confirms or contradicts that?

Comment: Does this help? [https://www.movieloci.com/pieceitem/location?id=2993-The-Best-Offer]. It would seem the film was made only near Prague and Vienna.

Comment: Update – No, it appears the locations are more diverse than that: Filming began in Trieste on April 30, 2012. For Tornatore this meant a return to Trieste: it was here he shot La Sconosciuta in 2005, with Xenia Rappoport. Filming took place in a period of five to six weeks in the region of Friuli-Venezia Giulia, Vienna, Prague, and South Tyrol. (Wikipedia) Thanks for drawing my attention to this film. I want to see it!

Comment: @Livrecache As I wrote I'm aware of the filming locations.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. I didn't get the impression that it was meant to be in an English-speaking country when I watched it. It's clear that it's set in Europe from the external location shots. And the interior, for that matter. Maybe where it is set is irrelevant. Afterall, Geoffrey Rush is Australian. That's an English-speaking country!

Comment: In fact, this review comments: http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/review/best-offer-film-review-408942. I don't how definitive it might be but it says: "Shot all over northern Italy, Vienna and Prague, the film’s precise setting is **deliberately left a blank**. As in the director’s A Pure Formality andThe Unknown Woman, the anonymous location 'somewhere in Europe' makes it easier to accept an international cast speaking English."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one interpretation:

> Shot all over northern Italy, Vienna and Prague, the film’s precise setting **is deliberately left a blank**. As in the director’s *A Pure Formality and The Unknown Woman*, the anonymous location “somewhere in Europe” makes it easier to accept an international cast speaking English.

See: [this review](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/review/best-offer-film-review-408942). I cannot verify its authority but it seems plausible to me.

Comment: I was suspecting this as well - I was thinking that it's either that or UK. If Tornatore has this custom of anonymous locations it's an acceptable answer to me (unfortunately I don't know any of his other works, apart from _Malena_). Thanks.